Unity mlAgents not connecting to Unity
I followed a tutorial on how to set up mlagents in unity and that all mostly went smoothly. I got a simple scene set up like this:

With 3 Walls that reset the Episode and give a negative reward and one "finishline" that rewards the AI when hit. I have a script for the carmovement which takes a input vector2d for steering and driving/reversing. I have created a script for the agent that gives the ai the transform of the car and the finishline
 public override void CollectObservations(VectorSensor sensor)
    {
        sensor.AddObservation(transform.position);
        sensor.AddObservation(targetTransform.position);
    }

and takes its output and moves the car with it
 public override void OnActionReceived(ActionBuffers actions)
    {
        stepCounter++;
        Debug.Log("Step: " + stepCounter);

        float moveX = actions.ContinuousActions[0];
        float moveY = actions.ContinuousActions[1];

        float distanceToGoal = Vector2.Distance(transform.position, targetTransform.position);
        Debug.Log("Distance to Goal: " + distanceToGoal);

        SetReward(-0.01f);

        if (distanceToGoal < goalThreshold)
        {
            SetReward(1.0f);
            EndEpisode();
            Debug.Log("Goal Reached!");
        }

        Debug.Log("Action Received: MoveX: " + moveX + ", MoveY: " + moveY);
        carController.SetInputVector(new Vector2(moveX, moveY));
    }

I added logs all over the place.
When I run the mlagents-learn command in cmd it tells me to start the game in unity, when I do that nothing happens in unity and the console prints some info about the trainer confi etc. The unity console logs that 1 time a episode was started but noting else, the Ai didnt give any output etc. after 1-2 minutes in cmd it says [WARNING] Restarting worker[0] after 'The Unity environment took too long to respond. My behaviour looks like this:

with 2 continuous actions for the steering and driving/reversing and a space size of 6 for the 2 vec3 transforms for the car and the goal.
I have these versions:

mlagents (unity plugin) 2.0.1
mlagents (python) 0.30.0
python 3.9.0
pytorch 1.7.1

At first I had some problems with numpy and soon but I could fix that by using compatible versions
As I said before it doesn't print anything in the console aside form starting the episode once, no ai inputs/outputs, no errors, nothing
I tried adding a maxstep number and that led to unity restarting the episode every 20ms but I don't think that information helps.
I run the mlagents command from a virtual environment and here is what the console say in detail.

